# Wordpress database configuration causing redirect loop

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

Everytime I deploy a major update and changes the database I have this problem. In this current project it's the third time it happens.

When I go to `WWW.mydomains.com.br` the website opens perfectly. If I go to `mydomains.com.br` I get a redirect loop problem. My website address and Wordpress address are both set to `http://www.mydomains.com.br`. If I remove the WWW i get the redirect loop when I access `WWW.mydomains.com.br`.

I add the `WP_HOME` and the `WP_SITEURL` constants to `wp-config.php` I still get this problem.

If I add or remove WWW with HTACCESS it seems to be ignored (well it doesnt seem to change anything).

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomains.com.br$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mydomains.com.br/$1 [R=301,L]
#or
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mydomains.com.br$
RewriteRule (.*) http://mydomains.com.br:80/$1 [R=301,L]
```

If I click on Permalinks page and redefine it, it is not helping.

**BUT** I am very sure that one or more of these solutions have already helped in the past, in one of my previous attempts to solve it.

It is always redirecting to itself, even if I remove the redirect rules of the .htaccess (or empty it).

I am using Openshift to host my files and Cloudflare as DNS server. This is the second project I work on and I have the same problem. I never understand how I fix it, so every new problem is a new challenge.

I believe it's the database because when I find a solution it gets ruined when I migrate the database again (after changing `localhost` to `mydomains.com.br`)

What am I missing? Is it a server cache?

Answer (score 0):

may be you need to check your "index.php", make sure there are no redirects inside it. This problem once happened to me because i had more than one redirect in my php. When it's the case, the browser gets confused on which 1 to choose hence crashes down...

Comment: There is not. It's the same index.php since I downloaded it

Answer (score 0):

in the index.php check all the include() files which are called by the index, it could be that 1 of them have sucessive redirect...maybe you need to state the problem graphycally 4 better understanding